# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/workspace/.next'

Tags: google-app-engine, nextjs-app-beta

deploying nextjs app to GCP app engine I got two errors:

`[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/workspace/.next']`

`"This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."`

## specifications:

- nextjs 13 (with experimental appDir feature)

next build and next start works in the local environment

Answer (score 2):

The notice of error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/workspace/.next</strong>'` shows that your Next.js app is unable to locate the "**.next**" directory, which should be located in the project's root directory.

This might be brought on by improper workspace directory permissions or failing to run "**next build**" before deploying to the Google Cloud Platform App Engine.

For additional debugging, you can try manually create the directory with the proper permissions or refer to the Google Cloud Platform App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/troubleshooting).

It only means that the initial request to your app might take longer to load and that the second warning notice is normal and can be disregarded